# Why do the JTAG parallel registers update on the falling edge?

Tags: jtag

The TMS state is change on the falling edge of the TCK clock. It is logical that the state of the chip TAP FSM is changes on the rising edge of the TCK clock. Data loading to the shift register on the Capture-XX state or shifting the shift register on the Shift-XX state are also deploying on the rising edge. Why do JTAG parallel registers update on the falling edge? Is there any reason why the standard says to do so?

Comment: They must update at *some* edge. Flip a coin, choose the edge, put it into standard. The standard says so because the standard has to make a choice.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica And here I was imagining that they wanted JTAG to work fine with a spring-loaded SPDT + SR latch for manual clocking. ;)

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica By a coin we can choose the edge of TMS changing. Let it "X". Then IC TAP FSM change state on invert "X". Some other actions are also deploying on invert "X". And only parallel register updating deploying on straight "X" on Update-XX state. I wonder what was the reason for doing this is in the standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not apply only to Update-DR. Update-IR latches instruction on falling edge, TDO updates on falling edge as well. It looks more like a general design pattern rather than just chance.

Advocating for this kind of pattern is handling TCK distribution skew wrt. hold time.  Remember TCK is distributed in parallel on the board.

Let's say you have a board where TCK has some non-uniform clock delay, then chip A receives TCK *x* ps before chip B. If there are some nets from B to A (including B.TDO -> A.TDI, if applicable) with a propagation delay of less than *x* ps, you may have unresolvable skew issues in cases where sampling and update happens on rising edge.

OTOH, if update happens on falling edge and sampling happens on rising, ATE can always limit clock frequency to get in a working condition.

At first, this advocates for having TDO only updated on falling edge, but with topologies like in figure 4-2 of IEEE-1149.1-2001, (reproduced below: two chains sharing TDI and TCK and TDO but not TMS), there is no requirement for various TAPs of the same board to be in the same state. Then when some TAP is in Capture-DR and other is in Update-DR, we get to the same kind of problem with boundary scan cells. So the standard enforces this requirement everywhere.

[image: Excerpt from IEEE-1149.1-2001, Figure 4-2]

Comment: figure 4-2?  Seems like something is missing....

Comment: How can some TAPs be in Capture-DR and other is in Update-DR when the TMS line is common for all ICs in the JTAG chain? And if we imagine that some of ICs have dedicated TMS lines, why they can't have also dedicated TCK lines?

Comment: Sorry, I referred to the standard. I inserted said figure in the post for more clarity.

Comment: @Arseniy, disjoint TMS and common TDI/TCK is probably not a common use case, but this is clearly considered by standard.

Answer (score 0):

From [Freescale Semiconductor Application Note AN2074 - DSP56300 JTAG Examples](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN2074.pdf)

> • Test Data Input (TDI). This input is used to transfer instructions and data serially into the device. TDI is sampled on the rising edge of TCK and has an internal pull-up resistor.

> • Test Data Output (TDO). This output is used to transfer data out of the device serially. TDO changes on the falling edge of TCK.

> The TAP [16-state TAP controller state machine] changes state based on the level of TMS. Transitions from one state to another occur on the rising edge of TCK. Instructions and data are transferred in through TDI, which is sampled on the rising edge of TCK, while data is transferred out through TDO, which changes on the falling edge of TCK. This sampling technique prevents the development of a race condition in the TAP.

From [Multi-ICE JTAG port timing characteristics](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0048/f/jtag-interface-connections/multi-ice-jtag-port-timing-characteristics)

> In a JTAG device that fully complies to IEEE1149.1, TDI and TMS are sampled on the rising edge of TCK, and TDO changes on the falling edge of TCK. To take advantage of these properties, Multi-ICE samples TDO on the rising edge of TCK and changes its TDI and TMS signals on the falling edge of TCK. This means that with a fully compliant target, issues with minimum setup and hold times can always be resolved by simply decreasing the TCK frequency, because this increases the separation between signals changing and being sampled.

By using different edges, set and hold times can be established to avoid race conditions and if race conditions is a problem, then it can be fixed by slowing down the clock.